# update Oracle table colums to replace values with regex

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a NVARCHAR column that I need to update some of the rows where the data is not in the same format.

I need to update all the columns which has a entry of `16/MAR/16` to reflect a default time as well, so only columns with just the date needs a default timestamp like `16/MAR/16 08:00:00`

selecting it is not really a problem as the below select statement does exactly that.

```
select (create_date || ' 08:00:00') newdate 
from table 
where regexp_like(create_date, '^[0-9][0-9]\/[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]\/[0-9][0-9]$');
```

which returns
newdate `16/MAR/16 08:00:00`

What I need to know is, how do I change the select statement to a update /replace create_date columns with newdate **safely**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple really....

```
UPDATE table
SET create_date = REPLACE(create_date, create_date, create_date || ' 08:00:00')
where regexp_like(create_date, '^[0-9][0-9]\/[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]\/[0-9][0-9]$');
```

As far as "safely" doing this, it is safe, your select is very specific, we just apply this to the update.